# Git: how to create different unmerged states?

Tags: git, git-status

When do different `git status` unmerged states occur, like `added by us`, `added by them` or `both deleted`?

I've tried to reproduce the latter by performing a merge where a file has been deleted in the current and merged-from branch, but I was not able to create this status.

Comment: "both deleted"? Is it about octopus merge? How can it be in usual two-parent merge?

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get all three by renaming a file differently in each branch.

```
git init
touch foo
git add foo
git commit -m 'initial commit'
git checkout -b tmp
git mv foo X
git commit -m 'rename to X'
git checkout -
git mv foo Y
git commit -m 'rename to Y'
git merge tmp
```

Now you have all three states.

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git add/rm ..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#       added by them:      X
#       added by us:        Y
#       both deleted:       foo
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: Nice demo. This helped me see what us vs them means. If I'm in branch A and I'm merging in branch B, branch A is "us" and branch B is "them".

Comment: Also - your example taught me `git checkout -`, which is like `cd -`; it means "checkout the branch I was on before switching to this one." For anyone else finding this, it only toggles between two branches; it doesn't maintain a history.

Comment: As of Git 1.9.3, this example does not appear to work anymore: no merge conflict are generated.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing this out.  [t/t7060-wtstatus.sh](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/t/t7060-wtstatus.sh) in git.git has all of the cases.  They're hard to decipher so I'll try to update my answer whenever I get some free time.

Comment: I can confirm this on git 2.7.4: no conflict. – But I do have a “added by us” somewhere else... Still not sure how “adding” can be in conflict...