# Reproducing Git merge conflict: DD

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I'm working on a test script and trying to reproduce git merge conflict DD when shown via "git status --short". I've seen this conflict type in the past.

- DD (unmerged, both deleted)

I keep coming up with no conflict with everything I try.

What steps do I need to perform to generate "DD" conflict? What does a "DD" conflict mean?

I saw this: [Git: how to create different unmerged states?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021649/git-how-to-create-different-unmerged-states/3305914#3305914)
But the steps listed there no longer produce any conflicts in later versions of Git.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git unmerged path issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207029/git-unmerged-path-issue)

Comment: I can't tell by that link what steps are needed to take to reproduce the DD status condition.

Answer (score 5):

Found a link to https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/t/t7060-wtstatus.sh. It's kind of hard to read, but it contains test code for all git conflict types.

To produce DD:

```
git init
echo test > main.txt
git checkout -b conflict && git add main.txt && git commit -m main.txt && 
git branch conflict_second && git mv main.txt sub_master.txt
git commit -m "main.txt renamed in sub_master.txt" && git checkout conflict_second
git mv main.txt sub_second.txt
git commit -m "main.txt renamed in sub_second.txt"
git reset --hard conflict_second
git merge conflict
```

Results in:

```
=->git status
On branch conflict_second
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)

        both deleted:    main.txt
        added by them:   sub_master.txt
        added by us:     sub_second.txt
```

Or

```
=->git status -s
DD main.txt
UA sub_master.txt
AU sub_second.txt
```

Comment: Should probably mention that `git merge` initially reports it as a `CONFLICT (rename/rename)`. It's just later that it leaves this particular signature in the index, to be shown by `git status --short`.