# Git conflict "both deleted"

Tags: git, merge, conflict, delete-file

I don't understand why "both deleted" is a status for unmerged paths.

If:

- OldStandard is the base
- NewStandard is the last commit on the trunk
- OldCustom is the branch (fork from OldStandard) we try to merge back in master

Why is there a conflict with some files marked as "both deleted"?

I understand the conflict for "both added", when one file is added in NewStandard, and another version of the file is added in OldCustom.

But, for deletion, what's the problem if the file has been deleted in NewStandard, and has also been deleted in OldCustom?  That's an equivalent state, nope?

Comment: Git needs to associate a commit hash with the deletion. Which commit should take ownership of the deletion here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reproducing Git merge conflict: DD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702944/reproducing-git-merge-conflict-dd)

Comment: I've seen "both deleted" in rebase conflicts as well as merge conflicts.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702944/reproducing-git-merge-conflict-dd) (suggested as a duplicate) :

you can see a "both deleted" when `branchA` has a `git mv oldfile newstandard` commit, and `branchB` has a `git mv oldfile newcustom` commit.

In that case, when trying to merge `customBranch` into `standardBranch`, `git` will report a conflict on three files :

```
both deleted:  oldfile
added by them: newcustom
added by us:   newstandard
```

---

Like any conflict, the final choice resides in your hands :

`git` merely highlight the fact that *maybe* there could be a problem in the fact that `newcustom` and `newstandard` live together in your final code version, and *maybe* this could be linked to the fact that both were created by being a copy of `oldfile`.

You get to manually fix that :

- if removing `oldfile` is the expected outcome : `git reset -- oldfile`,
- if keeping `newstandard` is the expected outcome, remove the other : `git reset newcustom && git rm newcustom`,
- if some parts of `newstandard` and `newcustom` should be merged : edit them by hand, or use a 3-way merge tool : `meld newstandard newstandard newcustom`
- etc ...

Comment: In that case, how can we decide which things to keep?  It'd make sense to accept the deletion, and then either `newcustom` or `newstandard` when finalizing the merge. But how can we clearly see we have to make a choice between those 2 files (when there are hundreds of conflicts)?  Using `git mergetool` does not help here, am I right?

Comment: @user3341592: you are right, `mergetool` will show you the "correct" 3 way merge only when solving a "both modified" conflict on one single file.